# Is $\mathcal{T'} = \{S : S \subset X, S^C \in \mathcal{T}\}$ a topology on $X$?

Tags: general-topology

If $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology on $X$, then is $\mathcal{T'} = \{S : S \subset X, S^C \in \mathcal{T}\}$ a topology on $X$? Since $S^C \in \mathcal{T}$, then $S$ is a closed set of $X$, if $X$ is endowed with the topology $\mathcal{T}$. But in the topology $\mathcal{T}'$, the roles seem to just be reversed so $S$ now becomes an open set of $X$ when endowed with the topology $\mathcal{T}'$ on $X$, but I'm not sure if it's still a topology or not since I can't explicitly check members of the set $X$ to see if their unions and intersections are in $\mathcal{T}'$ or not.

Comment: Is an infinite union of closed sets necessarily closed?

Comment: No, but we don't have any closed sets in $\mathcal{T}'$

Comment: Let me clarify: the sets which are in $\mathcal{T'}$ are the closed sets from $\mathcal{T}$.

Comment: Have you checked this with standard examples, like discrete, indiscrete topologies on a set, or $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathcal{T}'$ *can* be a topology on $X$, but in general it is not. It always contains $\varnothing$ and $X$, and it’s always closed under taking finite intersections. In order for $\mathcal{T}'$ to be closed under taking arbitrary unions, however, the family of closed sets of $\mathcal{T}$ must be closed under taking arbitrary unions, which means (by De Morgan’s laws) that $\mathcal{T}$ itself must be closed under taking arbitrary intersections. This is the case if $\mathcal{T}$ is the discrete or the indiscrete topology on $X$, for instance.

In general, however, this is not the case. For example, let $\mathcal{T}$ bye the usual topology on $\Bbb R$, and let $\mathscr{U}$ be the family of open nbhds of $0$; then $\bigcap\mathscr{U}=\{0\}$, which is not open, so in this case $\mathcal{T}'$ is not a topology.

> **Exercise.** Show that $\mathcal{T}$ is closed under taking arbitrary intersections if and only if each point $x\in X$ has an open nbhd $B_x$ that is a subset of every open nbhd of $x$. That is, each point of $x$ has a smallest open nbhd.

Answer (score 0):

No. Let $\mathcal{T}$ be standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$. and suppose $\mathcal{T}'$ be a toplogy.

Let $S_n=(-\infty,-\frac{1}{n}-1]\cup[1+\frac{1}{n},\infty)$, $S_n^C=(-\frac{1}{n}-1,1+\frac{1}{n})\in\mathcal{T}$ hence $S_n\in\mathcal{T}'$ by definition. If $\mathcal{T}'$ be a toplogy, it should be closed in union.

$S=\cup S_n=(-\infty,-1)\cup(1+\frac{1}{n},\infty)$, since $S^c=[-1,1]\not\in\mathcal{T}$,$S\not\in\mathcal{T}'$, we get a contradiction.